# Elasticsearch : retrieve all documents from index with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to retrieve documents from Elasticsearch in Python.

So I wrote this small code :

```
es = Elasticsearch(
            myHost,
            port=myPort,
            scheme="http")

request = '''{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'''

results = es.search(index=myIndex, body=request)['hits']['hits']

print(len(results))
>> 10
```

The problem is that it only returns 10 documents from my index when I expect to have few hundreds. How is it possible to retrieve all documents from the index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to solve this.

If you know the maximum amount of documents you will have in the index, you can set the `size` parameter of the search as that number or more. For example, if you know you will have less than 100, you can retrieve them this way `results = es.search(index=myIndex, body=request, size=100)['hits']['hits']`

If you don't know that number, and you still want all of them, you will have to use the `scan` function, instead of the `search` function. The documentation for that is [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan)